# Is it possible to add linter for Google Chrome extension project?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, linter

I would like to add a linter for an existing Google Chrome extension project, is there any chance to add a linter for this kind of project?

Instead of package.json I have manifest.json, so when I run `npm init @eslint/config`, I have an error saying I need to have package.json.

Comment: You can use and config eslint for extensions the same way it's done for any other type of project. There's nothing specific for extensions that you need to configure (manifest.json is unrelated). If there's an error you should add it to the question.

Comment: Judging by the error all you need is [create package.json](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+create+package.json).

Comment: @wOxxOm is it okay to have both manifest.json and package.json in Google Chrome extension project?

Comment: Of course it's okay. These files are completely unrelated.